# How to fix slow queries?

Tags: database, performance

I've logged slow mysql queries on D6 and came up with a large list. So I'm wondering where the queries are located and what is the best strategy to fix them? I also appreciate if you could point me to useful resources about query optimization in Drupal.

Comment: Indexes ! Take one slow query and add indexes for all. Check this out http://drupal.org/project/dbtuner

Comment: kantu, I already use DB Tunner but it has not solved the problem of long queries (+ 30s). So here I mostly look for manual query optimization guide.

Comment: Can you post one Slow Query ? And have you tried adding indexes for that particular tables ?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(comments.cid) AS cid, comments.subject AS comments_subject,  comments.nid AS comments_nid, comments.timestamp AS comments_timestamp FROM comments comments LEFT JOIN node node_comments ON comments.nid = ode_comments.nid
 INNER JOIN users node_comments__users ON ode_comments.uid = node_comments__users.uid
 WHERE (comments.timestamp < 1340703206+86400) AND (node_comments.status = 1) AND (node_comments__users.uid not in ('5622')) AND (node_comments__users.uid not in ('1'))
 GROUP BY cid  ORDER BY comments_timestamp DESC
) count_alias;

Comment: The above query takes 34s to execute. How can add index to a particular query like the above? Thanks

Comment: 34 seconds? How many records do you have in the comments/node_comments tables?

Comment: @Clive, The site is a big community site. Here is the part that I eliminated for the shortage of space# Query_time: 34.217171  Lock_time: 0.000185 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 0